# Jquery separate Multiple Select Options update price on change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have few individual products with an original price and each with a select dropdown and associated prices too, the original price changes based on the option selected, this is done via JQuery.

So Product 1 = 3.99, and optional addons (options from select) small = 1.50, Medium = 3.50 etc.

```
<p><span data-name="product_name">Addon Product</span></p>
<p data-name="product_desc">Addon product descriptions</p>
<label>Size: </label>
<select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
<option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
<option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
</select>
<span class="price pull-left" itemprop="price" id="price">&pound;5.99</span>
<hr/>

<p><span data-name="product_name">2nd Product</span></p>
<p data-name="product_desc">2nd Addon product description</p>
 <label>Size: </label>
<select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
<option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
<option data-price="20" value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option data-price="30" value="Large">Large</option>
</select>
<span class="price pull-left" itemprop="price" id="price">&pound;3.99</span>
<hr/>
```

There will also be Product 3, 4 and so on.

The input field name, price, id, class is being populated dynamically from a database so they are same for different Items.

If one product exists then it's fine however with multiple products and its options the price for the first ID only changes. As an example if I change the select from Product 2 then the price of Product 1 changes only. How can I get it to stick to its own Product and change the price for that one only?

Here's my code and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lenfeovs/)

```
var basePrice = +($('#price').html()).replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,"");
    $(".readers").change(function() {
      newPrice = basePrice;
      $(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
        newPrice += +$(this).attr('data-price')
      });
      $("#price").html("&pound;" + newPrice.toFixed(2));
      $("#new-price").val(newPrice.toFixed(2));
    });
```

Comment: You can only use IDs once. Give each of your elements unique IDs.

Comment: Ok is there a way to dynamically refer to an id with jQuery without specifying it implicitly because they'll be populated from a db and there's going to be n number?

Comment: The problem is, the ID's of the elements, the ID of each element should be unique. In your case the **span** element id is **price** in both the cases. make sure the `<Select>` element have unique id and also the  `<span>` element have unique Id.

Comment: There's a few ways you can do it. Either structure your HTML a bit more (put each product block within a div or something) and then traverse the DOM with `.parent`, `.children`, etc, or use `data-` attributes, or use concatenation where maybe the id of the select element is something like a product ID and then the id of the price span is something like "price-1234" and you then concatenate "price-" with the product ID.  Lots of ways to skin that cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this and fixed a few issues.  Your HTML was

1. Missing a number of closing tags
2. embedded the second product in the first products group

By making them separate groups and then using jquery code to lookup the parent group and then searching for child by CLASS in that group, was able to get the functionality you were looking for.

```
$(".readers").change(function() {
    // For each reader, need to go up to the form-groups parent to search for the price
  var productParent = $(this).parent().parent();
  // Need to get the base price from an attribute, otherwise it will change each time you make a selection
  var newPrice = parseFloat(productParent.find('.price').attr('data-price'));
  productParent.find(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
    newPrice += +$(this).attr('data-price')
  });
  productParent.find(".price").html("&pound;" + newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4rg0ou5e/